Upgrading to 24.04 broke my filesystem
I tried to upgrade from 22 to 24 yesterday. I used apt upgrade and followed the instructions, and I didn't see any errors during the installation.
When I rebooted, the filesystem was broken. No matter which GRUB entry (for this OS) that I select, I get timeout errors on mounting my disks.
I have an Ubuntu Live USB which I can log in with, and that sees the disks. I don't have a backup of my old fstab. I checked what I think is the right fstab, and I don't know if it is the source of the problem.
UUID=9ce87bbe-ecfb-4856-96bc-2635c7d4a3b1 / ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1 
UUID=152a0490-bd72-45e1-bf6c-f50be9711359 none swap sw 0 0
/dev/sdb1 /home/Archive ntfs auto 0 0

When I try to boot, I get a long hang, and then this:
[ TIME ] Timed out waiting for device **0-bd72-45e1-bf6c-f50be9711359
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for /dev*0-bd72-45e1-bf6c-f50be9711359 
[ TIME ] Timed out waiting for device /dev/sdb1
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for /home/Archive 

I don't see what is causing the problems. Why can't I mount my disks?

If this is the correct fstab, then the failing drives are the swap and an NTFS drive. Could it be you booted into another operating system in the meanwhile and something went wrong there?

I went directly from the upgrade to this error. This is a dual-boot laptop, but I have never had an issue with that before. The GRUB configuration has Ubuntu as the first OS on the list, and Windows at the bottom.
I have edited the fstab multiple times and none of them work. I also explored the Ubuntu re-install option, but there is no "/" mount option to install to.
The way it's set up is that /dev/sda1 is the windows NTFS partition, /dev/sda3 is the swap, and /dev/sda4 /dev/sda5 is the linux partition. I have not manually edited my fstab before, it just worked like this.
